# Excel VBA passing a variable into singe quotes

Tags: html, excel, vba

I cannot get the code below to accect the value I

```
   TimeFrame = Worksheets("Selector").Range("B1").Value 
   TimeFrame2 = CStr(TimeFrame)
    
    'HTMLDoc.querySelector("[name=AheadHour] option[value='8']").Selected = True   '<< this works!
    
    'HTMLDoc.querySelector("[name=AheadHour] option[value='Timeframe2']").Selected = True  '<< this does not work!
```

Comment: `TimeFrame2` still falls within the outer `""`... concatenate with `&`.

Comment: thanks!  Ths worked:

Comment: htmlDoc.querySelector("[name=AheadHour] option[value='" & TimeFrame2 & "'").Selected = True

Answer (score 0):

this worked - thanks BigBen!

```
Set htmlDoc = ie.document
TimeFrame = Worksheets("Selector").Range("B1").Value
TimeFrame2 = CStr(TimeFrame)

htmlDoc.querySelector("[name=AheadHour] option[value='" & TimeFrame2 & "'").Selected = True
```